# How to invalidate redis cache with mysql?

Tags: mysql, caching, redis, invalidation, cache-invalidation

I want to use redis as cache for mysql, and the main idea is:

Query

1. read from redis
2. if not exist, read from mysql, and add to redis cache

Add

1. write to mysql directly

Update&Delete

1. write to mysql
2. invalidate the cache of redis

My question is: how to invalidate the cache?

I know I can delete it, or set a expire time, is it a usual way, or are there any standard methods to invalidate the cache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You would need a trigger to tell redis that mysql data has been updated.

1. This can be a part of your code, whenever you save data to mysql, you invalidate the redis cache as well.
2. You can use streams like http://debezium.io/ to capture changes in the database, and take neccessary actions like invalidating cache.

Comment: so, how to invalidate data in redis?

Comment: Another option is to use a fake slave and be aware of what's going on in mysql. There are a few open source projects that can react to mysql changes without triggers.